# Как правильно переносить проект на примере Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Разрабатывал проект используя Yii2 basic и composer на локальном сервере. Теперь хочу перенести это на простой хостинг.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это делать, особенно интересует вопрос:

1. Нужно переносить только файлы yii2 или composer тоже?
2. Если нужно переносить, а потом на хостинге еще и устанавливать composer, то делается это через ssh?
3. Хостинг поддерживает установку composer только через VPS, можно ли перенести и запустить проект безе переноса composer?

Comment: Нафиг на боевом сервере композер? Вы же не будете там что-то докачивать с помощью него.. Просто копипаст проекта...только надо убедиться что версии php, mysql - такие же...Плюс желательно разрабатывать или протестить все на локальной линуксовой машине (банально поставить virtualbox). Ибо хосты на линухах все. А разработка если на винде - может чуть-чуть что-то не то быть...... но это вроде не такое частое явление

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Просите, чтобы Вам предоставили ssh доступ;
2. Если у Вас проект под контролем версий, то нужна установка git или svn, в зависимости, что у Вас.
3. Устанавливаете по ssh composer.
4. Делаете клон своего проекта на сервер.
5. потом composer install
6. Выполняете миграции.

Если у Вас проект не под контролем версии, то достаточно доступа по ftp,
просто берете и копируете файлы на сервер, composer не нужен.

Также нужно учесть что папка, которая в yii2, web , на сервере может называться public_html. Для этого сделайте символьную ссылку на папку